# Rigid Body does not Behave as Expected

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to create a trapeze. I am using cloth simulation for the ropes and for the handle I am trying to use a combination of an armature to drive a swinging motion and rigid body physics for free swinging.

To do this;

- I have the origin for handle at the swing point.
- I use "child of" constraint to control the position of the handle, key framed to turn off when I want the handle to fall naturally.
- I have a rigid body constraint between a passive object at the top where the trapeze swings from, and the handle.
- I am animating the rigid body physics for the handle so that animation is turned off close to top part of the swing.

What I expect to happen is that when the animation is turned off, the handle is then controlled by the rigid body physics and it should fall from its position constrained by the rigid body constraint to fall naturally.

Nothing remotely like that is happening. I have tried several methods but nothing is working.

What am I missing? I include the blend file to try:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was *"I have the origin for handle at the swing point."*

The rigid body constraint calculates from the origin point of the handle. So by having the origin point and the rigid body constraint at the same place was causing my problems. Once I moved the origin point to the handle, and gone through several crashes, I got the result I was expecting.